# How to design my message thread (within two person alternately)

Tags: javascript, html

I am making message thread between admin and the user my problem is here. When the admin sends a message, the thread load it goes on the right part of my modal and when the user message the admin  messages goes the left part. My codes run accordingly but messages dont display alternately. I think Im having problem with my css design.

Example scenario I have a conversatio between admin and user:

```
 USER: Do you have product xxxxx?

 ADMIN: Yes, maam we have xxxxxxx.

 USER: Thank you for the response.
```

In the message thread it display like this:

```
   Do you have product xxxxx?
   Thank you for the response.
                                      Yes, maam we have xxxxxxx.
```

It should display like this:

```
   Do you have product xxxxx?
                                      Yes, maam we have xxxxxxx.
   Thank you for the response.
```

Here are my codes:

This is my blade for displaying the thread:

```
<div class="row" style="  margin-left: 30px; margin-bottom: 5px; left: 20px; width: 530px; height: 200px; overflow: auto;">

                        <h6 style="color: blue;" id="thread_bsa"></h6>

                        <h6 style="color: green; margin-left: 200px;" id="thread_bsi"></h6>

                </div>
```

This is my javascript -> returning data to my blade:

```
function loadThreadMessage(refNumber, user){ 
            $.ajax({
                url: "loadThreadMessage",
                type: 'POST',
                headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
                data: "refNumber="+refNumber+"&user="+user,
                dataType: 'JSON',
                success: function(data){
                    $('#thread_bsa').empty();
                    $('#thread_bsi').empty();
                    $.each(data, function(key, value){
                        if(value.role == 'BSA'){

                            $('#thread_bsa').append('<p>'+value.message+'</p>');
                        }
                        else{

                            $('#thread_bsi').append('<p>'+value.message+'</p>');
                        }

                    }); //each
                }
            }); 
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You append your responses INTO the corresponding h6 elements. What you want to do is appending the response elements to the div.

Your current JavaScript function generates the following markup:

```
<div class="row" style="  margin-left: 30px; margin-bottom: 5px; left: 20px; width: 530px; height: 200px; overflow: auto;">

                    <h6 style="color: blue;" id="thread_bsa"><p>value 1</p><p>value 3</p></h6>

                    <h6 style="color: green; margin-left: 200px;" id="thread_bsi"><p>value 2</p></h6>

            </div>
```

So there is no problem with your CSS but with your JS. Assuming your div has the id 'div':

```js
function loadThreadMessage(refNumber, user){ 
        $.ajax({
            url: "loadThreadMessage",
            type: 'POST',
            headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
            data: "refNumber="+refNumber+"&user="+user,
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function(data){
                $.each(data, function(key, value){
                    if(value.role == 'BSA'){

                        $('#div').append('<p class="bsa">'+value.message+'</p>');
                    }
                    else{

                        $('#div').append('<p class="bsi">'+value.message+'</p>');
                    }

                }); //each
            }
        }); 
    }
```

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.bsa {
  color: blue;
  align-self: flex-start;
}

.bsi {
  color: green;
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="row" id="div">
<p class="bsi">dummy message 1</p>
<p class="bsa">dummy message 2</p>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not instead use CreateElement and put your text in spans and depending on whether they are admin or user you add in style="text-align:right/left"

Comment: The alignment of admin and user  is working but it didnt display the alternate conversation between the user and admin.